# Selenium on AWS Device Farm cant locate element by xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-device-farm

I'm new to ADF. I'm writing hybrid test scripts and I would like to know why it is not possible to find element thru its xpath on Amazon Device Farm Appium JUnit.

I tested and I can do this:

`action.click(By.id("menu"), "Click on menu");`

But I **can't** do this:

`action.click(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu\"]"), "Click on menu");`

I have a couple os test scripts which I used to test on SauceLabs and I had no problem with it. It could identify all the elements presents onscreen, but I haven't found any explanation of why xpaths are not accepted on AWS Device Farm.

Edit:
Error message

```
AppTest failed: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS). (WARNING: 
The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or 
timeout: 151 milliseconds For documentation on this error, please visit: 
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html Build info: 
version: '3.1.0', revision: 'b94c902', time: '2017-02-16 12:21:31 -0800' 
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: 
'1.8.0_151' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver `
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing an Android app, This `xpath` should work.

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'menu')]")
```

Also, don't forget to set the `automationName` desired capability.

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
action.click(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu']"), "Click on menu");
```

If not, [try your xpath expression](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) until it is valid.